# Python Peewee MySQL bulk update

Tags: python, peewee

I am using Python 2.7, Peewee and MySQL. My Program reads from a csv file and update the field if order number exists in the csv. There can be 2000-3000 updates and I'm using naive approach to update the record one by one, which is dead slow. I have moved from using Peewee update to Raw query, which is a bit faster. However, it is still very slow. I was wondering how do I update the records in fewer transaction without using a loop.

```
def mark_as_uploaded_to_zoho(self, which_file):
    print "->Started marking the order as uploaded to zoho."
    with open(which_file, 'rb') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, encoding='utf-8')
        next(reader, None) ## skipping the header

        for r in reader:
            order_no = r[0]
            query = '''UPDATE sales SET UploadedToZoho=1 WHERE OrderNumber="%s" and UploadedToZoho=0''' %order_no
            SalesOrderLine.raw(query).execute()

    print "->Marked as uploaded to zoho."
```

Answer (score 0):

The new best answer is to use [Model.bulk_update](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.bulk_update) with a transaction. The `batch_size` argument can be changed to tune performance.

```
# CSV generator for efficient memory usage
def gen_csv(file_name, header=True, **kwargs):
  with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, **kwargs)
    if header:
      next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
      yield row

# Update based on order number
with database.atomic():
  rows = gen_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
  SalesOrderLine.bulk_update(rows, fields=['OrderNumber'], batch_size=200)
```

Comment: The question asked is about bulk *update*, not insert.