# Speed of updating MySQL InnoDB data tables correlated with total number of records in table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, peewee

I am using **MySQL 8.0.30** to build a database, and created several **InnoDB** data tables. These tables have the same table design (columns and column types), but contain different number of records. Now I need to add a new column for all tables, and update that column one record by one record since every record has different value of that column.

I used **peewee 3.15.1** to perform the update. I only used two columns related to update, one is column `id` which is the primary key, the other one is the column `col_a` which needs to be updated. The `col_a` column has no index, and each table also does not have join relationships.

```
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type               | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col_a        | varbinary(1024)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I performed the update in chuncks. let's say, variable `MYSQLDB` is `peewee` database object, `table` is `peewee` data table object which needs to be updated, and `num` is the total number of records in that table.

```py
batch_size = 1e5
count = ceil(num / batch_size)

for i in tqdm(range(count)):
    this_min = int(i * batch_size)
    this_max = int((i+1) * batch_size)

    query = (table.select(table.id,
                          table.col_a)
                  .where(table.id > this_min,
                         table.id <= this_max))
    
    for j in range(len(query)):
        query[j].col_a = <corresponding binary string for that row>
    
    with MYSQLDB.atomic():
        table.bulk_update(query, fields=[table.col_a])
```

In each iteration, `peewee` will fetch 100K records and then update column `col_a`. I found **the running time per iteration was highly correlated with the number of records in table**.

| Data Tables | #Records | Rough estimated running time per iteration (seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table 1 | 60,329,700 | 227.75 |
| table 2 | 4,325,292 | 108.48 |
| table 3 | 3,433,891 | 101.94 |
| table 4 | 18,787,232 | 147.28 |
| table 5 | 25,605,277 | 168.04 |
| table 6 | 8,042,938 | 128.80 |
| table 7 | 10,652,355 | 135.54 |
| table 8 | 1,068,277 | 107.63 |
| table 9 | 1,189,886 | 117.33 |
| table 10 | 1,926,438 | 115.07 |
| table 11 | 7,590,218 | 118.50 |
| table 12 | 9,404,617 | 133.26 |
| table 13 | 1,033,066,290 | 5147.33 |

After exclude table 13, the Pearson correlation coefficient between running time per iteration and number of records in data table is 0.9815 (p-value = 1.649e-08).

[image: scatter plot with regression line]

I am new to MySQL, and my questions are:

1. Why the running time of updating the same number of records is correlated with the number of total records in that table? Is it because the time for locking rows increases along with the table size?
2. For updating table 13, the running time is not acceptable. In order to add the new column and fill corresponding values, should I dump all rows by `mysqldump` to a CSV file, then insert them back into a new table together with the new column?

Comment: do you know if peewee bulk_update is actually updating one row at a time?  if not, you could gain a lot by updating multiple rows at once

Comment: do you in fact need to do all the updates in a single transaction?

Comment: I don't need to update all rows in one transaction. The document of peewee [`bulk_update`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.bulk_update) function don't explain clearly how the update is performed. I saw `bulk_update` were answers for two related questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096473/bulk-update-using-peewee-library), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427755/python-peewee-mysql-bulk-update)). I am not sure how to update multiple rows at once given the values needed to be updated for rows are different.

Comment: you update multiple rows by joining your table from values table constructor: https://dbfiddle.uk/247CuCb7  the entire select has to be less than @@max_allowed_packet, but even with 1024 byte binary values, you should be able to do 100 at a time

Comment: anyway, I can't answer your basic question about why the correlation with table size, but I can point out you have a number of factors to try removing and see what makes a difference: your orm (try raw multirow updates), locking (just do autocommit for each update statement), whatever tqdm might be doing

Comment: bulk_update() is rather complex under the hood and probably not well-suited to this task. I suggest reading the code for the method to get an understanding of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @ysth @coleifer. I finally decide to read all columns from the original data table, add the corresponding values for the new column, then save into a new data table. Using peewee `insert_many` function gives acceptable running time even for the large table with 1 billion records.

Comment: I was going to suggest you could also use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (insert_many + on_conflict), docs here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#upsert